# How to correctly adjust a pandas dataframe row by row

Tags: python, pandas

My data frame has two columns: TimeStamp and Value (decimal).
I want to add a 3 new columns into the dataframe:
oneMinuteValue
fiveMinuteValue
fifteenMinuteValue

The data is in sorted order of ascending timestamp. From the first timestamp I want to go through every minute from the first timestamp until the last and execute the following:

for each row that has data from this minute, set the oneMinuteValue as either:
a) the final value from the previous minute; or
b) the current Value if this timestamp happens to sit directly on the minute to the second

I want the same for the 5 and 15 minute columns, but an example with just 5 minutes will be enough I think

An example (left off the fifteen minute one):

```
TimeStamp             Value    OneMinuteValue    FiveMinuteValue
2018-08-11 14:30:01   5        5                 5
2018-08-11 14:30:11   4.8      5                 5
2018-08-11 14:30:30   4.9      5                 5
2018-08-11 14:30:46   5        5                 5
2018-08-11 14:30:59   5.1      5                 5
2018-08-11 14:31:01   5.2      5.1               5
2018-08-11 14:31:20   5.3      5.1               5
2018-08-11 14:31:40   5.4      5.1               5
2018-08-11 14:32:16   5.5      5.4               5
2018-08-11 14:32:28   5.6      5.4               5
2018-08-11 14:33:04   5.6      5.6               5
2018-08-11 14:33:40   5.7      5.6               5
2018-08-11 14:34:01   5.7      5.7               5
2018-08-11 14:34:22   5.8      5.7               5
2018-08-11 14:34:32   5.8      5.7               5
2018-08-11 14:34:48   5.9      5.7               5
2018-08-11 14:34:59   6.0      5.7               5
2018-08-11 14:35:01   6.1      6.0               6
2018-08-11 14:35:21   6.2      6.0               6
```

Comment: last two - typo, edited. With regards trying to solve, I first tried group by but couldn't find out how to add custom logic and then came across using itertuples but several SO answers say you shouldn't modify the data frame using this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create boolean mask with [`floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) by expected time with [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) for keep only last value. Then use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) for create `NaN`s for all values without last. These values are [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed and `NaN`s are replace by forward filling. Last replace first group by first value of `Value` column:

```
first = df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc('Value')]
m1 = df['TimeStamp'].dt.floor('1Min').duplicated(keep='last')
df['1min'] = df['Value'].mask(m1).shift().ffill().fillna(first)
m2 = df['TimeStamp'].dt.floor('5Min').duplicated(keep='last')
df['5min'] = df['Value'].mask(m2).shift().ffill().fillna(first)

print (df)
             TimeStamp  Value  OneMinuteValue  FiveMinuteValue  1min  5min
0  2018-08-11 14:30:01    5.0             5.0                5   5.0   5.0
1  2018-08-11 14:30:11    4.8             5.0                5   5.0   5.0
2  2018-08-11 14:30:30    4.9             5.0                5   5.0   5.0
3  2018-08-11 14:30:46    5.0             5.0                5   5.0   5.0
4  2018-08-11 14:30:59    5.1             5.0                5   5.0   5.0
5  2018-08-11 14:31:01    5.2             5.1                5   5.1   5.0
6  2018-08-11 14:31:20    5.3             5.1                5   5.1   5.0
7  2018-08-11 14:31:40    5.4             5.1                5   5.1   5.0
8  2018-08-11 14:32:16    5.5             5.4                5   5.4   5.0
9  2018-08-11 14:32:28    5.6             5.4                5   5.4   5.0
10 2018-08-11 14:33:04    5.6             5.6                5   5.6   5.0
11 2018-08-11 14:33:40    5.7             5.6                5   5.6   5.0
12 2018-08-11 14:34:01    5.7             5.7                5   5.7   5.0
13 2018-08-11 14:34:22    5.8             5.7                5   5.7   5.0
14 2018-08-11 14:34:32    5.8             5.7                5   5.7   5.0
15 2018-08-11 14:34:48    5.9             5.7                5   5.7   5.0
16 2018-08-11 14:34:59    6.0             5.7                5   5.7   5.0
17 2018-08-11 14:35:01    6.1             6.0                6   6.0   6.0
18 2018-08-11 14:35:01    6.2             6.0                5   6.0   6.0
```

Another solution with loop:

```
cols = ['1Min','5Min']
first = df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc('Value')]

for x in cols:
    m = df['TimeStamp'].dt.floor(x).duplicated(keep='last')
    df[x] = df['Value'].mask(m).shift().ffill().fillna(first)
print (df)
             TimeStamp  Value  OneMinuteValue  FiveMinuteValue  1Min  5Min
0  2018-08-11 14:30:01    5.0             5.0                5   5.0   5.0
1  2018-08-11 14:30:11    4.8             5.0                5   5.0   5.0
2  2018-08-11 14:30:30    4.9             5.0                5   5.0   5.0
3  2018-08-11 14:30:46    5.0             5.0                5   5.0   5.0
4  2018-08-11 14:30:59    5.1             5.0                5   5.0   5.0
5  2018-08-11 14:31:01    5.2             5.1                5   5.1   5.0
6  2018-08-11 14:31:20    5.3             5.1                5   5.1   5.0
7  2018-08-11 14:31:40    5.4             5.1                5   5.1   5.0
8  2018-08-11 14:32:16    5.5             5.4                5   5.4   5.0
9  2018-08-11 14:32:28    5.6             5.4                5   5.4   5.0
10 2018-08-11 14:33:04    5.6             5.6                5   5.6   5.0
11 2018-08-11 14:33:40    5.7             5.6                5   5.6   5.0
12 2018-08-11 14:34:01    5.7             5.7                5   5.7   5.0
13 2018-08-11 14:34:22    5.8             5.7                5   5.7   5.0
14 2018-08-11 14:34:32    5.8             5.7                5   5.7   5.0
15 2018-08-11 14:34:48    5.9             5.7                5   5.7   5.0
16 2018-08-11 14:34:59    6.0             5.7                5   5.7   5.0
17 2018-08-11 14:35:01    6.1             6.0                6   6.0   6.0
18 2018-08-11 14:35:01    6.2             6.0                6   6.0   6.0
```